# Binding TextColor of Label inside StackLayout with BindingContext

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, xamarin.forms, staticresource

I need to Bind `TextColor` of `Label`. But the `Label` is inside a `StackLayout` with `BindingContext` of `SelectedArticle`, hence the Binding is not working with anything outside `SelectedArticle` for Binding (**am I wrong here?**)

`public Color ArticleFontColor { get; set; }`

```
<StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding SelectedArticle}">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large"
           TextColor="{Binding ArticleFontColor}"
           FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Thinking that, I tried using Style, but the value wont bind.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
          <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding ArticleFontColor}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>


<Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large"
           Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
           FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
```

`TextColor` can be changed runtime, thats why I need binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I found this solution:

Add `x:Name` tag to your `ContentPage` or root Layout.

eg.

`<ContentPage 
...
...
x:Name="MyRoot">`

Then, use that `x:Name` as a reference and get its `BindingContext`

`TextColor="{Binding BindingContext.ArticleFontColor, Source={Reference MyRoot}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Styles won't work with values from bindings.

**First option:**
You don't need styles for that:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Large"
           TextColor="{Binding ArticleFontColor}"
           FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
```

If `ArticleFontColor` is not a `Color` type (eg. only `string`) you should use a `IValueConverter` implementation to do the conversion (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/ - search for IValueConverter).

**Second option:**
Use triggers to set styles: 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/triggers/ (Data Triggers section)

Comment: `ArticleFontColor` is a `Color`
Also, my first code snippet IS your First Option. But its not working, probably because its parent `StackLayout` is has a `BindingContext` to `SelectedArticle`.

`ArticleFontColor` is NOT a property instide `SelectedArticle`. Thats why the question.